# Login form validation using xmlHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I am having a simple html page for login. The html will look like,

```
<form action="createUsers.html" method="post" onsubmit="return loginValidation();">
```

I am using the ajax for it. if the user is not available, it will display error msg in the login page. else it will navigate the user to createUsers.html page.
The javascript file will look like and it will call the servlet,

```
if((document.getElementById("user").value !="")&& (document.getElementById("pass").value != "")){
        var params = "&user=" + uname + "&pass=" + upwd;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
          {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
          xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
          }
        else
          {// code for IE6, IE5
          xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
          {
          if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)    
        {           
            var result = xmlhttp.responseText;           
            }
          }

        xmlhttp.open("POST","login",true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlhttp.send(params);
        alert(result)
             if(result=="success"){
                  return true; 
              }
              else if(result=="failure") {
              document.getElementById("errormsg").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
              return false;
              }
    }
```

This ajax call will check for the user in the database and it will return success if the user is available.

The problem is that, always the code is calling the else if statement, even if the value of result is success. Even the alert statement is also displayed as success. I am not sure why it is not comparing the result=="success" statement ?

Answer (score 1):

AJAX are by default asynchronous calls...
Your callback function is actually returning value (true/false) to xmlHttp object through onreadystatechange but not to your validation function which is associated to HTML window DOM object. Your validation function simply returning true to your form submit event and that's why you anyway make it navigate/submit to next page... 
You should call form.submit from your callback function itself on success result, you just need to retrieve form element object in your callback. And add "return false" in 'onSubmit' to avoid form getting submitted automatically.
Hope you understood the problem.

Comment: Thanks rahul.. Yes i understood it.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ((document.getElementById("user").value != "") && (document.getElementById("pass").value != "")) {
    var params = "&user=" + uname + "&pass=" + upwd;

    // declare it here
    var result;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            // accessing to parent scope`s variable
            result = xmlhttp.responseText;
            callback(result);
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("POST", "login", true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send(params);

   function callback (data){
     var result = data;
     alert(result)
    if (result == "success") {
        return true;
    }
    else if (result == "failure") {
        document.getElementById("errormsg").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        return false;
    }
   }

}
```

Comment: i moved the if statement inside onreadystatechange handler and it is working fine. But now i got another problem. if the result is failure, i am returning false to html page, it should only display the error message in html page, but it is also navigating to createUsers.html page. This page should be navigated only if the result is success.

Comment: this is my form in html page `<form action="createUsers.html" method="post" onsubmit="return loginValidation();">`. If the result is failue, i am returning false, but it shows the error message in html page, after that it navigates to createUsers.html

Answer (score 0):

Your callback function is actually returning value (true/false) to onreadystatechange but not to your validation function. Your validation function simply returning true to your form submit event and that's why you anyway make it navigate/submit to next page... 
You should call form.submit from your callback function itself on success result, you just need to retrieve form element object in your callback. And add "return false" in 'onSubmit' to avoid form getting submitted automatically.
Hope you understood the problem.

Comment: Got posted twice by mistake :-P